# How does -fPIE flag generate different code?

Tags: gcc, compilation

`-fPIE` is used to generate position-independent code that can be linked into executables.

For a simplest example:

```
int var;
extern int ext;
void foo();
int main(){
        int a = var;
        int b = ext;
        foo();
}
```

`gcc -fPIE -c so.c` and `gcc -c so.c` both generate the same instructions and relocations.

```
$ gcc -c so.c -o so.o
$ gcc -c -fPIE so.c -o so.fpie.o
$ diff <(objdump -Dr so.fpie.o) <(objdump -Dr so.o)
2c2
< so.fpie.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
---
> so.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

This is part output of `objdump -Dr so.o`

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # e <main+0xe>
                        a: R_X86_64_PC32        var-0x4
   e:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  11:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 17 <main+0x17>
                        13: R_X86_64_PC32       ext-0x4
  17:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  1a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  1f:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   24 <main+0x24>
                        20: R_X86_64_PLT32      foo-0x4
  24:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  29:   c9                      leave
  2a:   c3                      ret
```

My question is:

1. GCC manual says `-fPIE` flags is an `Option for Code Generation`, does that mean it only affects the stage of generation of asm, not preprocessing and assembly?
2. In which cases, `-fPIE` actually generate different object files(or instructions)? In my tests on x86_64 with gcc 12.2.1, it always generate same `.s` asm files when compiled with `gcc -fPIE -S` and `gcc -S` as the former example indicates:

   - Access external functions. It generate `R_X86_64_PLT32` relocation.
   - Access global variables in shared library or other object files. It generate `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation.

   I think it's rational (or preferred) to generate identical code without performance penalty. I'm just curious in which case the `-fPIE`
   flag actually generate different code and why.

Comment: next time post the relevant text from the "GCC manual" in question since the statements made here are too vague.

Comment: you are probably thinking of pic and not pie?

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int x;
void fun ( void )
{
    x=5;
}
```

gives

```
0000013c <fun>:
 13c:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
 140:   e59f3010    ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; 158 <fun+0x1c>
 144:   e59f1010    ldr r1, [pc, #16]   ; 15c <fun+0x20>
 148:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
 14c:   e7933001    ldr r3, [r3, r1]
 150:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
 154:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
 158:   00010090    muleq   r1, r0, r0
 15c:   0000000c    andeq   r0, r0, ip

Disassembly of section .got:

000101e0 <.got>:
   101e0:   00010160    andeq   r0, r1, r0, ror #2
    ...
   101ec:   000101f0    strdeq  r0, [r1], -r0   ; <UNPREDICTABLE>

Disassembly of section .bss:

000101f0 <x>:
   101f0:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

with -fPIE (as documented in the "GCC manual").

as an object.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   4:   e59f3010    ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; 1c <fun+0x1c>
   8:   e59f1010    ldr r1, [pc, #16]   ; 20 <fun+0x20>
   c:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
  10:   e7933001    ldr r3, [r3, r1]
  14:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  1c:   00000008    .word   0x00000008
  20:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

without -fPIE

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   4:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 10 <fun+0x10>
   8:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  10:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

and

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <fun>:
    8000:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
    8004:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 8010 <fun+0x10>
    8008:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    800c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    8010:   00018014    andeq   r8, r1, r4, lsl r0

Disassembly of section .bss:

00018014 <x>:
   18014:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Comment: Is the example code compiled for arm architecture? I just tested on x86_64 and aarch64, the resutl is: on x86_64: `no flag` == `-fPIE` != `-fPIC`; on aarch64:  `no flag` != `-fPIE` == `-fPIC`

Comment: yes arm is easier to demonstrate with.

Comment: yes this is covered in the documentation

Comment: fpie and fpic do make a difference as you probably know, but you seem to be focused on fPIE for some reason.    Which is not an SO question....this is a question for the gnu compiler folks.